# Count number of times symbol dropped X% in next 6 months in Amibroker AFL

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, amibroker

I am using Amibroker ver6.20.1. I would like to count the number of times a stock price dropped X% from a certain day in the next 6 months using AFL code. This will require using Ref() to reference future values.

https://www.amibroker.com/guide/afl/ref.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are looking at the Close price for the past 6 months as there is no charting software that can give future price figures. Here are the assumptions that I make for the AFL code below.
1. 6 months past Close price or 26weeksX5days/week = 130days
2. Compare X% of daily close price
3. Stock price dropped i.e. yesterday's Close price > today's Close price

```html
// BarCount is the number of element in Close array.
// Array element start from 0 to BarCount - 1.
// Create Close_price[i] array because Amibroker does not allow Close[i] in an If statement.
// X% is set to 15%.
// Run this AFL in Exploration and select Apply To : All Symbols, From to Date : Current date of your database
Close_price=Close;
Filter = 0;
x=0.05;
j=0;
if (BarCount >= 130) { /* Scan those stocks with at least 6 months data. */
for (i = BarCount - 130; i<BarCount-1; i++){
 if (Close_price[i] > Close_price[i+1] and (1-Close_price[i+1]/Close_price[i])>0.15){
  Filter = 1;
  j++;
  }
}
AddColumn(j,"# of time drop more than 5%",1.0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can count back how many times price dropped below -1.5% from day before in the last 20 days:

```
N = Sum(ROC(C,1) < -1.5, 20);
```

You can also convert it to future instances in the next 20 days as follows:

```
N = Ref(Sum(ROC(C,1) < -1.5, 20), 20);
```

The second solution will not work in real trading though, as, I'm sure, you know.